# Signal Handler to stop Timer in C

Tags: c, linux, exception, signals

I am trying to have a signal handler stop a timer without exiting my program. How should I go about. I want StopTimer to handle the signal to stop the timer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INTERVAL 2      // number of seconds to go off

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

TimerSet(INTERVAL);

while(1)
{
    // do stuff
}
return 0;
}

void TimerSet(int interval)
{
printf("starting timer\n");
struct itimerval it_val;

// interval value
it_val.it_value.tv_sec = interval;
it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

// on SIGALRM, close window
if (signal(SIGALRM, TimerStop) == SIG_ERR)
{
    perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
    exit(1);
}

// set interval timer, returns SIGALRM on expiration
if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1)
{
    perror("error calling setitimer()");
    exit(1);
}
}

void TimerStop(int signum)
{
printf("Timer ran out! Stopping timer\n");
exit(signum);
}
```

I tried to set the setitimer interval to 0, but I am not sure how to use the same timer within the TimerStop signal handler function

Comment: Just set `it_interval` to zero before you call `signal()`, and you'll get a one-shot timer, and you won't have to do anything in the handler.

Comment: Before you call `setitimer()`, not `signal()`. You also never set the `tv_usec` members of your `struct itimerval`, which is not good.

Comment: You should not use fprintf() and friends from within a signal handler. fprintf() is not signal safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `it_interval` to zero, and you'll get a one-shot timer. You don't need to do anything with it in your handler.

For instance, with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INTERVAL 2              // number of seconds to go off

void TimerStop(int signum) {
    printf("Timer ran out! Stopping timer\n");
}

void TimerSet(int interval) {
    printf("starting timer\n");
    struct itimerval it_val;

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = interval;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    if (signal(SIGALRM, TimerStop) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    TimerSet(INTERVAL);

    while (1) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the message `"Timer ran out! Stopping timer"` will appear only once, and your timer will stop without you doing anything.

Note that you need to fill in the `tv_usec` members of your `struct itimerval`, which your current code does not do. If you don't, `it_interval` is highly unlikely to be zero, and your timer will never stop.

`printf()`, along with the other standard IO functions, is not really safe to call from a signal handler, although in this particular case it won't cause you any problems, since the main code is just sitting in a loop and not doing anything.

Also, presume you're calling `signal()` on purpose - `sigaction()` is the recommended way for setting handlers. `setitimer()` is also obsolete, now, and `timer_settime()` is recommended.

Comment: I want to have my timer run later at some point in my program. I made it_val global, and have a function that changes the interval. However, the timer stops forever. How can I make the timer go ON and OFF when I want it to? setitimer can only be run once.

Comment: What makes you think `setitimer()` can only be run once? You make it go off by calling `setitimer()` with everything zero, and make it go on by calling it with something else.

Comment: You are correct, I must have done something wrong earlier. THis works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to manual:

```
   Timers  decrement  from  it_value  to zero, generate a signal, and reset to
   it_interval.  A timer which is set to zero (it_value is zero or  the  timer
   expires and it_interval is zero) stops.

   Both  tv_sec  and  tv_usec are significant in determining the duration of a
   timer.
```

So timer can be set to run only once if interval is set to zero before setitimer() call (thanks to Duck's comment).

Comment: I am getting this error: error calling setitimer(): Invalid argument.
When trying to stop the timer. ALso when I set the interval to 0, it does not stop the timer

Comment: `setitimer` isn't safe to call from w/i a signal handler.  I think OP just wants to shut down the timer.  All he needs to do is zero out the interval values when he creates the timer.

Comment: @Olihoops I fixed my answer. As mentioned in man (and as Duck recommends) - it also possible to set interval to zero before starting timer.

Comment: I want to have my timer run again at some time later in the program. I tried making the interval global and have a function change the interval so that my timer starts again. However, the timer only runs once now.